# Alternative to ANOVA when observations are derived from one another

Tags: anova, independence

I have a bizarre statistics problem that appears easy at first glance.

I have some time series process, f(x), that is unknown but is hypothesized to be reactive to some known external event in some of the regions collected out of each sample. For simplicity, let's say there are two regions. I also have two kinds of samples, one of which I suspect should not be reacting to this external stimulus in either region. These regions are homologous across all samples. So I have two sets of samples (lets say 3 in each group, for simplicity), and I think at least one of the regions within these samples are reacting to the external event for one group, but I'm not sure how to model f(x).

So, what I've done is correlated, within each group, for each sample, for each region, the time series data collected with the other two samples, averaged them, and stored that number as the inter-sample correlation for that region for that group. This is believed to represent the presence (high correlation) or absence (low correlation) of some process f(x) that is reacting to the external stimulus, as my measurement noise is not believed to correlate between samples at all.

The data therefore looks something like this for a single region of interest (ROI) that hypothetically is presenting process f(x) in group 1, but not 2:

```
| sample | group | roi | correlation |
--------------------------------------
|    1   |   1   |  1  |     0.12    |
|    2   |   1   |  1  |     0.14    |
|    3   |   1   |  1  |     0.16    |
|    4   |   2   |  1  |     0.01    |
|    5   |   2   |  1  |     0.05    |
|    6   |   2   |  1  |     0.03    |
```

I would think that this would be a simple 2x2 (group x region) ANOVA and be done with it, but **each correlation value is derived from  correlations with all other samples in the group**. Therefore I think I violate the independence assumption even though the independence assumption is not normally framed this way.

If this is true, what would the appropriate test be to determine which regions show an inter-sample correlation difference?

Thanks in advance.